# What was the function of the Lycian spelling m̃m and ñn

Tags: phonology, anatolian

I am trying to understand the function of double (?) nasals in Lycian. Usually an /ñ/ is followed by /n/ and so does /m̃/ which is followed by an /m/. What was the function of this spelling in Lycian? Did they really try to produce both nasals or is it an attempt to render a nasal that has lacked a letter.

Comment: Those were originally perhaps syllabic [m] and [n], later coda [m] and [n].

Comment: Good question! I've also seen them listed as syllabic nasals, but they almost always precede normal <m> and <n>. I don't know Luwian very well, but it's entirely possible that <m̃m> and <ñn> were their ways of writing the syllabic nasals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Kloekhorst 2008](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/kadm.2009.47.issue-1-2/kadmos.2008.011/kadmos.2008.011.xml?) writes the following:

> "the difference between /n/ vs. /nn/ and /m/ vs. /mm/ is only relevant
>   in initial and intervocalic position. In all other cases the ‘geminate’
>   spellings with -ñn- and -m̃m- are automatic and directly comparable
>   to the geminate spellings of the other consonants (p. 128).

He also provides an extremely useful chart:

[image]

If I understand [Melchert 1994](https://brill.com/abstract/title/30169?rskey=ybzmlN&result=1) correctly, this gemination could be viewed as "continuants spreading across a syllable boundary" (p. 265), e.g.

Arm̃ma- = [arm.ma-] < /arma-/

If such a cluster was in initial position, then an anaptycic vowel was insterted there:

km̃mi- [kəm.mi-] < /kmi-/

Comment: Thank you very much! The chart link is broken though.

Comment: @Midas Which link doesn't work for you? Kloekhorst 2008?

Comment: Forget it. I was refering to https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdfXP.png
I am temporarily in a country that tends to block various internet resources. I logged remotely to a computer at home and I can see the image. You don't need to edit anything. :)